# invertir string usando metodos de stack

Tags: javascript, stack

Tengo que invertir una string usando metodos de stack sin usar metodos de arreglo.
Este es mi código:

```javascript
function Stack() {
  this.array = [];
}
Stack.prototype.add = function(x) {
  this.array.push(x)
}
Stack.prototype.delete = function() {
  this.array.pop()
}
Stack.prototype.print = function() {
  return this.array
}
function mirror(str) {
  let reversed = ''
  let bank = new Stack();
  for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    bank.add(str[i])
  }
  for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    reversed += bank.delete()
  }
  return reversed;
}
```

Debería: mirror('prueba') --> 'abeurp'
Pero me regresa un string lleno de undifined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no se si te sirva

```js
function Stack() {
  this.array = [];
}
Stack.prototype.add = function(x) {
  this.array.push(x);
}
Stack.prototype.delete = function() {
  this.array.pop();
}
Stack.prototype.print = function() {
  return this.array
}
function mirror(str) {
  let reversed = ''
  let bank = new Stack();
  for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    bank.add(str[i])
  }
  for(let i = str.length-1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
    reversed += bank.array[i];
  }
  bank.delete();
  return reversed;
}

console.log(mirror('prueba'));
```

lo único era invertir el for secundario